# Display Windows Phone Splash Screen For Longer Period

Tags: windows-phone-7, splash-screen

I was just wondering if there's a way one could display the windows phone splash screen a little while longer. The way it is now (the default) the splash screen displays for something like half a second and then launches into the app. So it's literally just a flash.

I understand for user experience a splash screen is something rather pointless but, specs are specs in the business.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The splashscreen is displayed while your application is being loaded, so the time depends on the complexity of your code. You can create a XAML page with your splashcreen, set it as entry point, wait the desired time and then redirect to your main page.

Comment: I cant think of a better way to do it, had this problem before and solved it the same way you suggested :)

Comment: @Igor Kulman Sounds like the best way to go about it then. How do I then "switch-off" or bypass the default splash screen since I'll be using my own XAML screen?

Comment: @DeanGrobler You just have to remove the SplashScreenImage.jpg from your project, and then use your own XAML screen as soon as the application starts. Make sure you don't block the UI thread if you have any animations going on in your new splash screen.