# How to make splash screen appear for longer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an app that I am working on. I need the splash screen to display for atleast 1 full second (3 seconds maximum is preferred) - just long enough for you to be able to have a glimpse of the entire splash screen and be able to read the title (comfortably, not having to try hard to catch it before it goes away).

I have read the docs on Splashscreens on Windows Phone 8 on MSDN and it says:

> Typically, you should use a splash screen in your app only if your app
>   is unusually slow to load *or if you want to add additional branding to
>   the app*. If you decide to use a splash screen in your app, you have
>   two options.

My app is not the kind of app where users will need to get it quick, quickly do something and then leave the app - so there is no need for anything to be rushed.

So, I have successfully got the splashscreen to appear. BUT, the problem is that the app loads *too quickly* for you to be able to notice the splashscreen.

How can I programatically make the splash screen appear for a second or two? Can you set a time on it? Can you make it stay on for longer?

Comment: Personally, even if I don't need to access the app quick, it would still annoy me every single time the splash screen appears for more than a second. Even one second is already pretty much..

Comment: Then disable it in Settings.

Comment: Settings -> "Make Splashscreen shorter".... Yeah. Good one! I'd just think "Why not in the first place, if it's possible?!" Do you want your app do stand out with a Splashscreen, or with the app itself?

Comment: Why limit the app to where it can stand out?

Answer (score 5):

> The splashscreen is displayed while your application is being loaded,
>   so the time depends on the complexity of your code. You can create a
>   XAML page with your splashcreen, set it as entry point, wait the
>   desired time and then redirect to your main page.

Source:
[Display Windows Phone Splash Screen For Longer Period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823701/display-windows-phone-splash-screen-for-longer-period)

Answer (score 5):

The solution you want to use (thread.sleep) is not a very good solution it should be used only for app you're not gonna put in the Windows store. The official solution by microsoft is to use a XAML page as a splash screen (as posted by polymorphin). I used the xaml page solution before and It's way better than blocking the UI thread for 2 reason:

1. Blocking the UI thread is not good and may flag your app during windows store validation process, making it not pass.
2. During the splash screen you have  time to do initialization of your app component using the async model.

In a previous project I had to show the splashscreen for 3 seconds (it was an animated gif), and during that i was able to establish connection with server and start geolocalization service using code similar to this:
e.g.

```
List<Task> tasks=new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Task.Delay(3000));  // time used by splash screen
tasks.Add(MyComponent1.DoWorkAsync());
tasks.Add(MyComponent2.DoWorkAsync());
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);   //wait for all the task to complete
```

Comment: Hey this is great. And you saved me from having to resubmit my app. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Just create a page which looks exactly like the splash screen and show that first, immediately after the splash screen. Navigate from it after a second or two.

Enable the user to switch it off in the settings, though. Nobody wants to wait more for the app to load than it's necessary **every time**.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe how bad my memory can be at times. I just found this in one of my older WP8 apps:

```
    // Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
    // This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Seconds + 3000);
    }
```

Works like a charm! Put this in your App.xaml.cs file and it will show the SplashScreen (if you have one) for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I found that tuto :

[link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Custom_splash_screen_page_for_Windows_Phone_applications)

Basicly you need to do :

- create a xaml 'SplashPage.xaml'
- into the "SplashPage.xaml"'s XML :

  - To hide the status bar change : shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" -> shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
  - Add you image : `<Image Source="/splash.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>`
- into the "SplashPage.xaml"'s CODE :

> - Add all the code you need into "Loader" 
>     Blockquote

```
public SplashPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += SplashPage_Loaded;
        }

        void SplashPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //ADD YOUR CODE
        }
}
```

> - and when you want to show your 'MainPage.xaml' call :

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

- into the "MainPage.xaml"'s CODE :

> - To reset all page in the stack do that (with that code you remove SplashPage from the stack :D ):

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you just sleep the app for a second during its loading phase?

[Sleep / pause a function in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178287/sleep-pause-a-function-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score -1):

A quick search shows another user that had this problem:

[WPF SplashScreen , how to make splashscreen showing longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739412/wpf-splashscreen-how-to-make-splashscreen-showing-longer)

```
SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
splashScreen.Show(false);
```